# Getting JSON for Angular 2 from HTTP remote server fails, but succeeds localy

Tags: angular, angular-http

I'm trying to read a JSON file using htttp.get in Angular2.

When I use a file stored **localy** on my project, **it works OK**.

But - when I use a **remote server**, with **exactly** the same file, I get the following error:

> **404 - Not Found Collection 'undefined' not found**

Browsing to `http://example.com/my.json` , I can see the file on any browser.

Here is my typescript code for getting the file:

```
private url = '../my.json';   <--- This works
private url = 'http://example.com/my.json';   <--- This throws the error


return this.http.get(this.url)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a problem with the angular. This is the server side/backend problem. You should not serve json on this way.

Comment: @IgorJanković Can you please explain ?

Comment: What language do you use on the server side?

Comment: @IgorJanković There's no language... It's just a JSON file sitting under the site directory.

Comment: Did you success to get json file when input URL on browser? Does it response your expected json?

Comment: @ManhLe Yes, I get exactly the same file.

Comment: `Not found collection` error sounds to me that you for your previous usage of http you have used in-memory-web-api?? You need to scrap that to get it to work :)

Comment: @AJT_82 Hi, Yes, I have import { InMemoryWebApiModule }     from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';  - What should I do with it? What should I replace it with ?

Comment: Just remove everything related to the in-memory-web-api from your project :) Following this: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html should include everything to you need to do for doing http-calls with "real data".

Comment: @AJT_82 I can't just remove it, I use it like this: import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';

Comment: Yes, you need to remove it to get http to work. Because now it's looking for using the in-memory-web-api, but you don't want that, you want to make http-calls to external api and db.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Not found collection` error suggest that you have used `angular-in-memory-web-api` before. You need to remove everything related to that from your project, that would equal removing from `imports` in your `NgModule` the equal of the following:

```
InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService)
```

so that you are able to use external api and db.

Otherwise your code shouldn't change, but if you want, following [**this tutorial**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html) should help you.

Comment: BTW: Now I get a response with 0 - {"isTrusted":true} and in chrome dev I see: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Any ideas?

Comment: That's a problem on the api side. You need to set the Access. Not knowing what you use, when I use php I add `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` on the server side. Depending on your backend you need to check how to set that. If this is just a testing, you might need to enable cors in your browser. But for "better solution" you need to dig into how to allow cors in your api.

Comment: Thanks buddy. Have a great day.

Comment: You are welcome! Glad I could help! And you have a great day too, and happy coding! :)

Comment: Just solved the problem. I feel so great. AJT - love you buddy. Peace and love from Israel.

Comment: Yeah, you feel like a winner whenever you solve a problem :D Greets from a snow-stormy cold hell-hole in Finland :D