# Loadin a json file from angular2 for a particular object caused 404 error

Tags: json, angular, angular2-observables

I am trying to build an app using Angular2 but I am running into a problem when I do a get request by id for a certain product. 
  Some of the files related to my problem are given below:

product-list.component.html

```
  <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor='let product of products | productFilter:listFilter'>
                    <td>
                        <img *ngIf='showImage && product.imageUrl'
                             [src]='product.imageUrl'
                             [title]='product.productName | uppercase'
                             [style.width.px]='imageWidth' 
                             [style.margin.px]='imageMargin'>
                    </td>
                    <td><a [routerLink]="['/product', product.id]">
                             // when I click over this in web browser the URL is "http://localhost:4200/product/1" which is exactly what I want 
                            //but I got the following error in console: GET http://localhost:4200/assets/product.json/1 404 (Not Found)
                        {{product.productName}}
                        </a>
                    </td>
```

My json file is as below :

```
[ 
   {
    "id": 1,
    "productName": "Leaf Rake",
    "productCode": "GDN-0011",
    "releaseDate": "March 19, 2016",
    "description": "Leaf rake with 48-inch wooden handle.",
    "price": 19.95,
    "starRating": 3.2,
    "imageUrl": "http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/26215/Anonymous_Leaf_Rake.png"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "productName": "Garden Cart",
    "productCode": "GDN-0023",
    "releaseDate": "March 18, 2016",
    "description": "15 gallon capacity rolling garden cart",
    "price": 32.99,
    "starRating": 4.2,
    "imageUrl": "http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/58471/garden_cart.png"
    },
    // other objects
 ]
```

My service file is as below

```
  import { IProduct } from './product';

 @Injectable()
 export class ProductService {
private baseUrl = './assets/product.json';

constructor(private http: Http) { }

getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => <IProduct[]> response.json())
        .do(data => console.log('getProducts: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}


getProduct(id: number): Observable<IProduct> {
    if (id === 0) {
    //return Observable.of(this.initializeProduct());
 return Observable.create((observer: any) => {
        observer.next(this.initializeProduct());
         observer.complete();
     });
    };
    const url = `${this.baseUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get(url)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .do(data => console.log('getProduct: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

When I do a **getProducts()** call I have no error and all the products in Json format are loaded properly but when I do **getProduct(id)**, I got the above error.

What I mean by getProducts() call is the lines of code below which is located in my product-list.component.ts

```
 ngOnInit() : void {
    this._productService.getProducts()
    .subscribe(products => this.products=products,
                error => this.errorMessage = <any> error);
  console.log(this.products)
 } // this works perfectly
```

By getProduct(id) I mean the lines of code below

```
    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(
         params => {
            let id = +params['id'];
             this.getProduct(id);
     }); // this one is now working properly since I got a 404 error
```

I am not sure if my problem has to do with proper loading of json file but I think since I am able to retrieve all the products there is something wrong with routing or I am missing something.

I am running into this problem for two days and I was not able to find a proper solution in google so I decided to ask for help 
 Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked that the url is correct for your get request?

Comment: I mean 404 error means that the url you are trying to reach does not exist, you need to check your url :)

Comment: @AJT_82 By url you mean the url where json file is or the url of the browser ?

Comment: I mean your request url yes... and, now I see from your question... it clearly states that the url you are trying to reach is not found, so the follwoing url is wrong: `GET http://localhost:4200/assets/product.json/1 404 (Not Found)` like the error says :)

Comment: You are using a static json file? You cannot make post requests to that (or get requests with url parameters). If you don't have a real backend, I would suggest this InMemoryWebApi. here's how to setup that: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html# You can make POST requests to that.

Comment: @AJT_82 Yes you are right. Actullay I have a typerscripte file using InMemoryWebApi with a createDb() method, but when I use this InMemoryWebApi I am not able to get all the products and I console.log the error and the error is : "Collection 'product' not found "

Comment: That sounds like a missmatch. `Collection` errors happen when you mix "real http" and the in memory web api.

Comment: You need to check your code and follow the link I provided if you want to use the in memory web api, there has to be an error somewhere in your setup if you are getting that error. Here's a question and answer regarding the error (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42386685/getting-json-for-angular-2-from-http-remote-server-fails-but-succeeds-localy), this answer would not solve your issue, but maybe help you understand the error :) Follow the link I provided here in comments about the inmemoryap, and the one I provided in the links and get the correct setup for your http :)

Comment: @AJT_82 Can you give me a hint how to use in memory web api in my service in order to call the json format?

Comment: I cannot really help you there any further than supplying that link I gave: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html# Following that *should* get it working. If you cannot solve it, I suggest you need to open up a new question regarding that to get some help with the setup of it. I can't really supply any closer help, since I only know it in theory, have not used inmemoryapi myself. But as said, if you can't solve, post a new question about that, I'm sure someone can help you with that! :)

Answer (score 1):

i also faced this error and finally found the solution. Even though the solution is clear it works perfectly
make changes as below

```
private baseUrl ='assets/product.json';
```

should not give as

`'./assets/product.json'` or `'src/assets/product.json'`
product.json file should be placed in assets folder